# Angular /NgRx - Pass generic type in Effect

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I would like to create an action and an effect that take a generic type, but I do not know how to pass the generic type to the effect

minimalist code that works without the generic type in effect:

Component:

```
this.store.dispatch(
  new fromDialogActions.OpenDialogAction<DetailComponent>({
    component: DetailComponent, config: DIALOG_CONFIG
  })
);
```

Action:

```
export class OpenDialogAction<T> implements Action {
  readonly type = DialogActionTypes.OPEN_DIALOG;
  constructor(public payload: OpenDialogPayload<T>) {}
}
```

Effect:

```
export class DialogEffects {
  @Effect({ dispatch: false })
  openDialog$: Observable<null> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(fromDialogActions.DialogActionTypes.OPEN_DIALOG),
    map((action: fromDialogActions.OpenDialogAction<DetailComponent>) => action.payload)
  );
}
```

How to pass a generic here: `map ((action: fromDialogActions.OpenDialogAction <DetailComponent>) => action.payload)` instead of `DetailComponent`? Ty

Comment: do you mean `<any>` ?

Comment: @ShashankVivek yes we can put `any`, but I try to pass a generic type like in action

Comment: If you want to put generic type in effect you do that simply by `.ofType<Class>()`

Comment: Why would that be of any help? I an usually against using any at all but here you definitely don't need a generic